# How set geolocation to the model with 'Autodesk.Geolocation'

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have an application for converting DWG files, and I need to display these files on an ArcGis map.
How can I add geolocation to my file? When I add a location to AutoCad and open a file in forge application, the location properties are empty and hasGeolocationData() returns false.

I tried add location in dwg file with AutoCAD 
![AutoCad - screen]: https://ibb.co/HtBLpg5
but
![location is empty - screen]: https://ibb.co/dQWmz9M
and tried set `e.lmvToLonLat({x:-20.871083468967406, y: 6.520671770079398})`,
but getting an error:

> index.js:175 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'lmv2LL84Point' of null
>       at t.value (index.js:175)
>       at viewer.js:56

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, args => {

  viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Geolocation')
      .then(e =>  {
        console.log(e.hasGeolocationData())
        e.lmvToLonLat({x:-20.871083468967406, y: 6.520671770079398})
        e.activate()
      })
});
```

Comment: Did you add the geolocation following [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-4138A163-80D8-435B-B1FD-878E14FC8E9F-htm.html)? If yes and the geolocation data is still missing after translation (check with `viewer.model.getData`) pls send the drawing to forge.help@autodesk.com so we can look into it...

Comment: thanks Bryan! I will send the drawing to forge.help@autodesk.com. Can you give me a test drawing with geolocation that I can open in the forge-viewer? Maybe I'm setting the location in AutoCad incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Engineering just confirmed that the extractor responsible for the geolocation data is taken from Civil 3d - their team examined your drawing and suggested the following:

> EDITDRAWINGSETTINGS and select the coordinate system that the project is in